# Calendar to return only day of the week and time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: android, time, calendar

```
public Calendar getDayOfTheWeekTimeCalendar() 
{ 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
                8); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); >
        return calendar; 
    }
```

When I use above method I get the Calendar as Thrusday Dec 13 08:30:00 EST 2012  
My question: I have only setted day of the week, time ( hour, minute and second) why is it giving me date because I only want the calendar to return day of the week and time

SO that my task will be recursive, executes on every thrusday apart from doing for one week and stopping of

So that I can perform a task on every thrusdays at 8:30:00 EST but not only for current week that is  Dec 13th week

Comment: I dont really understand your question, but surely if you want to get a specific field use myDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

Comment: I have to schedule a task using day of the week and time so when I try to use Calendar, it would give me as Thrusday Dec 13 08:30:00 EST 2012 but I want only time and day of the week so that my task is recursive -- for all thrusdays it schould schedule the task. Right now when I schedule it, it only executes on Dec 13th thrusday. I want my calendar to be recursive like for all thrusdays at this time schedule my task

Comment: Sorry I cant help. I suggest you read the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar.getInstance() gets the current date/time. you didn't specify the date, so it is today.

from the Javadoc...

Like other locale-sensitive classes, Calendar provides a class method, getInstance, for getting a generally useful object of this type. Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time:

`Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: thanks david  But is there a way were I can get only day of the week and time so that my task should be executed day of the week and time basis </br> Can you please suggest me by modifying the code

Comment: you want your function to return only "Friday 08:30" as a string? look at SimpleDateFormat().